# React Class Component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, rendering

All my components were rendering until I added the `Click` and `Counter` components. Here is `Click` :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Click extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
         count: 0
      }
    }

    UpdateClick = () => {
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
    }

  render() {
    const {count} = this.count;
    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick = {this.UpdateClick}>Click {count} time</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Click;
```

Here is Counter:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    
      this.state = {
         count:0
      }
    }

    IncrementCount = () => {
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
    }

  render() {
      const {count} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <button onMouseEnter = {this.IncrementCount}>incremented by {count}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {ClassComponent, ClassComponent2} from './components/ClassComponent';
import Click from './components/Click/Click';
import Counter from './components/Counter/Counter';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Navbar/>
     <ClassComponent/>
     <ClassComponent2/>
     <Click/>
      <Counter/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The console is NOT returning any errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `IncrementCount` in `Counter`:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
        count:0
    }
    this.IncrementCount = this.IncrementCount.bind(this);
}
```

...and `UpdateClick` in `Click`:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    }
    this.UpdateClick = this.UpdateClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: I rebuilt the component and saved each time I added a new line to see when everything dissapears. It's when I had

const {count} = this.count;

That is when everything goes away and stops rendering

Answer (score 0):

You have exported the `Counter` component like,

```
export class Counter
```

and imported as a default import

```
import Counter from './components/Counter/Counter';
```

To fix this either do a default export as you have done in `Click` component or do the non default import like below

```
import { Counter } from './components/Counter/Counter';
```